# istio session based out of process mixer adapter Validate/CreateSession/CloseSession never called

Tags: grpc, istio

I'm trying to build an istio out of process mixer adapter.

Everything worked fine after few attempts and I **now want to be able to configure my adapter** using the "session based" adapter model.

If I understood the concept correctly, I only need to :

- Create a config.proto with my parameters :

```
syntax = "proto3";

package config;

import "gogoproto/gogo.proto";

option (gogoproto.goproto_getters_all) = false;
option (gogoproto.equal_all) = false;
option (gogoproto.gostring_all) = false;

message Params {
  string value1 = 1;

  string value2 = 2;
}
```

- compile it with protoc to output a descriptor_set file
- base64 this descriptor set in adapter.yml

```
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: adapter
metadata:
  name: exampleadapter
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  description: "A sample adapter for test purposes"
  session_based: true
  templates:
    - ...
  config: ...config.proto descriptor set base64 encoded ...
```

- implement this gRPC protobuf interface :

```
syntax = "proto3";

package istio.mixer.adapter.model.v1beta1;

option go_package="istio.io/api/mixer/adapter/model/v1beta1";
option cc_generic_services = true;

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";
import "google/rpc/status.proto";


service InfrastructureBackend {

  rpc  Validate(ValidateRequest) returns (ValidateResponse);

  rpc  CreateSession(CreateSessionRequest) returns (CreateSessionResponse);

  rpc  CloseSession(CloseSessionRequest) returns (CloseSessionResponse);
}

message CreateSessionRequest {
  google.protobuf.Any adapter_config = 1;
  map<string, google.protobuf.Any> inferred_types = 2;
}

message CreateSessionResponse {
  string session_id = 1;
  google.rpc.Status status = 2;
}

message ValidateRequest {
  google.protobuf.Any adapter_config = 1;
  map<string, google.protobuf.Any> inferred_types = 2;
}

message ValidateResponse {
  google.rpc.Status status = 1;
}

message CloseSessionRequest {
  string session_id = 1;
}

message CloseSessionResponse {
  google.rpc.Status status = 1;
}
```

- Create a Handler istio config file that set the config values :

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: handler
metadata:
  name: h1
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  adapter: exampleadapter
  connection:
    address: exampleadapter:9070
  params:
    value1: testVal111
    value2: testVal2222
```

So I've done all this steps, but **my Validate/CreateSession methods are never called**.

I tried to check mixer (istio-policy) logs, even in debug, but I don't have any clues why this config step is totally ignored !

Would someone have any ideas ? Something obvious I missed ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on the Istio GitHub Issue tracker : https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19194#issuecomment-558922143

**TL;DR :** It's not implemented yet and there is no plan to release this feature in foreseeable future.